# Kafka Error : Kafka process is going down frequently. Showing below error when trying to restart this

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-connect

Thanks in advance. Please help me to resolve this below mentioned kafka error.

```
00000000000000.txnindex and rebuilding index... (kafka.log.Log)
[2018-09-25 12:48:05,462] ERROR There was an error in one of the threads during logs loading: java.lang.InternalError: a fault occurred in a recent unsafe memory access operation in compiled Java code (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2018-09-25 12:48:05,469] FATAL [KafkaServer id=0] Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
java.lang.InternalError: a fault occurred in a recent unsafe memory access operation in compiled Java code
        at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(HeapByteBuffer.java:57)
        at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:335)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.record.FileLogInputStream$FileChannelRecordBatch.loadBatchWithSize(FileLogInputStream.java:209)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.record.FileLogInputStream$FileChannelRecordBatch.loadFullBatch(FileLogInputStream.java:192)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.record.FileLogInputStream$FileChannelRecordBatch.ensureValid(FileLogInputStream.java:164)
        at kafka.log.LogSegment$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(LogSegment.scala:263)
        at kafka.log.LogSegment$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(LogSegment.scala:262)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
```

Comment: What is the output of `df -h`?

Comment: what version of Apache Kafka are you running?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your Kafka log directory (`log.dirs` in `server.properties`) is out of memory. When Kafka attempts to rebuild the index, there is insufficient memory and therefore Kafka broker cannot be started. 
Assuming `log.dirs=/var/lib/kafka`

```
df -hT /var/lib/kafka
```

will display storage usage for your log directory.